# Regex - How can I insert text before each line?

Tags: regex, automation, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text, with the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-z0-9!@#$")(*&!+_-]
```

This is what happens:
[image]

The first character is selected.

I need to put the "Replace With" text before the strings, without damaging the first character.

How can I do that?

Comment: What was the intention behind placing this vague image? How this image  supports your question?

Comment: @Dinooppaloli It shows that the first character of each line is being highlighted when the regular expression is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the regex matching `^` with you text to replace.
I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

find what : `^(.*)`

replace with : `hello \1`

this will prepend hello to each line of your text